# Dynamic Programming-- Variable Width Bin (Equi-Depth) Histogram

Tags: recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given some data, and a fixed number of bins (k)-- How can I design a Dynamic Programming algorithm that minimizes the largest difference between bin sizes?

In other words, with a set number of bins (k), I am looking to adjust the width to make them all as equal as possible.

I have read this paper, however, it doesn't really handle what I am trying to accomplish.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.5578v3.pdf

Can I somehow modify their algorithm for my purposes or is there another approach I should look at?